# POST large json string from Javascript to Django

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, cordova

I have a small cordova (phonegap) mobile app with simple form. I need select a file, fill other fields and save form. Then I want to send this data later.

**How I save my form data:**
form fields in localStorage as json string of serialized array, and file in LocalFileSystem as reader.readAsText() in file (just file with base64 string).

**How I send data to server:**
I push base64 string to my serialized array and make an ajax post to server stringified data.

**My problem:**
I cant send large json string (when file > 2 MB) to my server, I get an error: **code 414, message Request-URI Too Long**.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You are doing something in a wrong way. Send `HTTP POST` request from javascript.

Comment: I do $.ajax({...})

Comment: Check. I added answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this like this.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<URL_HERE>', // where data should be send
  dataType: 'json',
  data: '{"a": "b"}', // your json data here
  success: function(data) {
      // This will be invoked, if server returns status code 200.
      console.log(data)
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Django settings!

**DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE** - by default it is 2.5 MB (2621440).

**DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 26214400** solved my problem (25MB)